# Calculate the volume swept out when the top half of the elliptical region bounded by...

Tags: calculus, rotations, volume, solid-of-revolution

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi80E.png)

*Work the problem by substituting a=4 and b=3, then solve usin direct integration.*

Not sure where to get started here. Some guidance would be appreciated. Pretty sure this just requires creating the equation and just straight solving but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the distance from the x-axis of the ellipse as the radius of a circle.

Comment: Well I understand that much, but not sure what integral (what bounds) am I setting up here.

Comment: Use the $y=b\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ form of the equation. Your bounds should be the minimum and maximum values of $x$ that produce a real result.

Comment: so I get bounds -4 to 4. Integrate 3sqrt(1-(x^2/16)), and then it looks like I start substituting trig to find the answer. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, but because the formula is $\int_a^b\pi*r^2$, you shouldn't have to use any trig.

Comment: Oh ok. So I'm literally just integrated A(r)dr, and that's the volume I'm looking for?

Comment: $r=3\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{16}}$